# PyFlink - How can I push data to mongodb and redis by using PyFlink?

Tags: python, mongodb, redis, apache-flink, pyflink

I'm new to PyFlink.

Recently, I use PyFlink to complete a feature that read stream data from Kafka and insert it to another Kafka.

Now, I want to push data into mongodb and redis. But I read the documents and search this question on search engine and I don't get any useful solution.

In documents, there are some connector with Kafka, file system etc. It seems that there's no solution for mongodb and redis.

So, how can I push data to mongodb and redis by using PyFlink?

Thank for your help firstly !!

Answer (score 1):

There are no official Flink connectors for mongodb or redis.

The Apache Bahir project does have a redis sink for Flink: https://flink-packages.org/packages/apache-bahir-redis-connector.

If you use google to look around (or if you search on github) you will find that several folks have implemented simple mongodb sinks that you might find workable, depending on your requirements.

As for making these connectors work with PyFlink, there I'm not sure.